# Retrieve all match records from mongodb depend on multiple condition

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I have the my mongodb collection schema in following format

```
    { 
    "_id" : 1,
    "sid" : 11,
    "shapes" : [
      {"shape" : "square",  "color" : "red"},
      {"shape" : "circle",  "color" : "green"},
      {"shape" : "rectangle",  "color" : "green"},
      ......,
      ......,
      {"shape" : "elipse",  "color" : "green"}
      ] 
    }, 
    ........,
    ........,
    { 
    "_id" : 100
    "sid" : 111,
    "shapes" : [
      {"shape" : "square",  "color" : "red"},
      {"shape" : "circle",  "color" : "green"},

       ......,
      {"shape" : "rectangle",  "color" : "green"}
      ] 
    }
```

And I want to Retrieve record from it where **sid = 11** and **shape like %r%** using java driver.
I used the following code but it give me only first record ,please suggest me what I doing wrong ?

```
            DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("sid", 1);
            DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*r.*"); 
            searchQuery.put("shape", regex);
            DBObject elemMatchQuery = new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", searchQuery);

            DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
            fields.put("shapes", elemMatchQuery);

            DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, fields);
            System.out.println(cursor.count());
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
```

Comment: The [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)  operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria, so above query match only first matching array value if you find all matching data use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I am beginner sir can you suggest the code for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongo `aggregation` query as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$match":{"sid":11}},{"$unwind":"$shapes"},{"$match":{"shapes.shape":{"$regex":".r."}}})
```

and equivalent java code as :

```
    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("sid",11);
    BasicDBObject firstmatchObj = new BasicDBObject();
    firstmatchObj.put("$match", match);
    BasicDBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$shapes");
    BasicDBObject matchAfterUnwind = new BasicDBObject("shapes.shape",new BasicDBObject("$regex",".r."));
    BasicDBObject secondmatchObj = new BasicDBObject();
    secondmatchObj.put("$match", matchAfterUnwind);
    List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    pipeline.add(firstmatchObj);
    pipeline.add(unwind);
    pipeline.add(secondmatchObj);
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
    for (DBObject res : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , I got my result.